# Not able to pass dynamic image value (base64 format) during PDF generation using Apache FOP

Tags: apache, pdf, xslt, apache-fop, dynamic-image-generation

I am using FOP library to generate pdf from a xml file, able to generate all the data(except image) with dynamic info passed through another xml. Its not allowing me to pass image value as below

```
<fo:inline>  
          <fo:external-graphic content-width="109.5pt"
                                    content-height="50.25pt"
                                    src="<xsl:value-of select="paymentno" />"
            </fo:external-graphic >
</fo:inline>
```

where xml data which is being passed dynamically is

```
`<tns:paymentno>
"url(&quot;data:image/auto;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFUAAAAoCAIAAAAAKyESAAAAYUlEQVR42u3PQQoAIAgEwP7/6YIiEC3oGownjWVjWt/T5qwlvqQz5utyKzkGUvJYlX55aahnjOUAPz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/P/+H/gGaQxUFTT6pUgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==;&quot;)"</tns:paymentno>`
```

One more thing, if i am passing static value(of image) directly to xsl then i am able to get image in my pdf.
Please do provide me with solution if you have any idea asap

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL is incorrect. You cannot just put xsl:value-of inline. See this answer for inspiration to write the template.

[Inserting a base64 encoded image into xsl-fo file while using apache-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013882/inserting-a-base64-encoded-image-into-xsl-fo-file-while-using-apache-poi/24295046#24295046)

Answer (score 0):

You will be passing your result to an XSL function, so you can just read the value directly.

```
<fo:inline>
    <fo:external-graphic
        content-width="109.5pt"
        content-height="50.25pt"
        src="url({paymentno})">
    </fo:external-graphic >
</fo:inline>
```

If you really wanted to use value-of, then you will use it to set an xsl attribute. From memory this should be (untested):

```
<fo:inline>
    <fo:external-graphic
        content-width="109.5pt"
        content-height="50.25pt">

        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="paymentno"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

    </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:inline>
```